# Camel Spring JMS Queue Connection Example

Tags: java, spring, queue, apache-camel, jms

I have 3 JMS queue's I need to test on a server. I have the following properties for these queues:

1. Hostname
2. Port
3. Channel
4. Queue Manager
5. Queue Names

I am looking for a way in which to test these queues through a java program. I would like to just have a simple main class to test these queues. One that I can modify the queue properties (particularly in a spring config file) and ensure I can message the queue and receive my message when I call to grab it.

I would just like to send the queue `Hello World!` and recevie back `Hello World!`

I assume this has been done time and time again, but I cannot find any resources that use properties for the queue other than the example below:

```js
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
 from("activemq:queue:test.queue")
 .to("stream:out"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to connect to an IBM MQ server. You simply need to configure a JMS component and configure an MQConnectionFactory using the values for those properties.

See this related article: [Apache Camel: Is it possible to configure WMQ without using Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014807/apache-camel-is-it-possible-to-configure-wmq-without-using-spring)